# When is the constant C part of the function when integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Lets take the following example:

$\int \frac{x-4}{(x-2)(x-3)}dx$

The result I get is $2\ln|x-2|-\ln|x-3|+C$

The result in my testbook is:

$\ln \frac{C(x-2)^2}{x-3}$

As $\ln \frac{C(x-2)^2}{x-3} = \ln(x-2)^2 - \ln|x-3| + \ln C$ and $\ln C$ can be every possible rational number, I assume that this is not wrong, but do I have to write it this way?

Comment: As it stands, your question is very unclear. What do you want to know about $C$?

Comment: Sorry, I clicked on submit before I was ready

Comment: Aestethic one might say it looks better. I would also add $C>0$. Just dont get confused with the constants like I did here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835773/differential-equation-from-an-exam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have indicated $$ \ln \frac{C(x-2)^2}{x-3} = \ln(x-2)^2 - \ln|x-3| + \ln C$$
Thus you do not have to change your answer to the compact form unless it is specifically required.

I would check the similar problem's answer in the back of the text book to see what format is used and follow the same format.
Specially  if it is a homework problem and is graded by a graduate assistant who accepts the solutions which are exactly like what is in the back of the book or in the solution manual.

Answer (score 3):

I think both answers they are wrong.

The right answer is
$$\int\frac{x-4}{(x-2)(x-3)}dx=\ln(x-2)^2-\ln(3-x)+C_1$$ for $x<2$,
$$\int\frac{x-4}{(x-2)(x-3)}dx=\ln(x-2)^2-\ln(3-x)+C_2$$ for $2<x<3$ and
$$\int\frac{x-4}{(x-2)(x-3)}dx=\ln(x-2)^2-\ln(x-3)+C_3$$ for $x>3$.

Comment: Good point... I didn't bother with the modulus signs ....as the question is specifically about the constant I think your answer is the best....

Answer (score 1):

$2\ln (x-2) -\ln(x-3)+\ln c=\ln (x-2)^2 -\ln(x-3)+\ln c=\ln\frac{c(x-2)^2}{x-3}$

so you are right ... and so is your textbook.... well done!

Comment: You have $2 ln(x- 2)- ln(x- 3)+ ln c= ln(x- 2)^2- ln(x- 3)+ ln c= \frac{c(x- 2)^2}{x- 3}$.  Surely you mean $2 ln(x- 2)- ln(x- 3)+ ln c= ln(x- 2)^2- ln(x- 3)+ ln c= ln\frac{c(x- 2)^2}{x- 3}$.

Comment: oooops   I'll edit that    thanks